# How to get href value inside td tags in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all `href` links inside `td` tags based on the `td` string. I have successfully managed to get all `href` links with the BeautifulSoup module but I am interested in only specific `href` links under `td` tags where that `td` class contains specific string. Is it possible to extract these with the BeautifulSoup module or any other module in Python?

```
      <td title="" class="pass">
          <a href="link info">
            <div class="fill"></div>
          </a>
      </td>

      <td title="" class="fail">
          <a href="inlk">
            <div class="fill"></div>
          </a>
      </td>

      <div class="fill"></div>
   </a>
</td>
```

I am interested to get all `href` links in this webpage where `td` class is `pass`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup,SoupStrainer
import requests
import re
c_link = 'your_link'
r = requests.get(c_link)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer("td"))
x = soup.findAll("a")
for tr in x:
    links = tr.get('href')
    print links
```

This will fetch you the href from the td that are present in the page. Hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for link in soup.select('td.pass a[href]'):
    print link['href']
```